# Maven wont install Lwjgl

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, lwjgl

I'm using maven on eclipse. I want to use Lwjgl and a few other libraries but Maven wont install them. It says they are missing. Here is what it says when I look at the errors:

```
ArtifactDescriptorException: Failed to read artifact descriptor for slick:slick:jar:274: ArtifactResolutionException: Failure to transfer slick:slick:pom:274 from http://slick.cokeandcode.com/mavenrepo was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of slick has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer artifact slick:slick:pom:274 from/to slick (http://slick.cokeandcode.com/mavenrepo): null to http://slick.cokeandcode.com/mavenrepo/slick/slick/274/slick-274.pom pom.xml /TheLabyrinth

Missing artifact java3d:vecmath:jar:1.3.1   pom.xml /TheLabyrinth

Missing artifact junit:junit:jar:4.10   pom.xml /TheLabyrinth

Missing artifact net.java.jinput:jinput-platform:jar:natives-linux:2.0.5    pom.xml /TheLabyrinth   line 1  Maven Dependency Problem

Missing artifact net.java.jinput:jinput-platform:jar:natives-osx:2.0.5  pom.xml /TheLabyrinth

Missing artifact net.java.jinput:jinput-platform:jar:natives-windows:2.0.5  pom.xml /TheLabyrinth   

Missing artifact net.java.jinput:jinput:jar:2.0.5   pom.xml /TheLabyrinth

Missing artifact net.java.jutils:jutils:jar:1.0.0   pom.xml /TheLabyrinth   

Missing artifact org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:jar:1.1 pom.xml /TheLabyrinth   

Missing artifact org.lwjgl.lwjgl:lwjgl_util_applet:jar:2.8.4    pom.xml /TheLabyrinth   

Missing artifact org.lwjgl.lwjgl:lwjgl_util:jar:2.8.4   pom.xml /TheLabyrinth   

Missing artifact org.lwjgl.lwjgl:lwjgl-platform:jar:natives-linux:2.8.4 pom.xml /TheLabyrinth   

Missing artifact org.lwjgl.lwjgl:lwjgl-platform:jar:natives-osx:2.8.4   pom.xml /TheLabyrinth   

Missing artifact org.lwjgl.lwjgl:lwjgl-platform:jar:natives-windows:2.8.4   pom.xml /TheLabyrinth   

Missing artifact org.lwjgl.lwjgl:lwjgl:jar:2.8.4    pom.xml /TheLabyrinth

The container 'Maven Dependencies' references non existing library 'C:\Users\Wyatt\.m2\repository\java3d\vecmath\1.3.1\vecmath-1.3.1.jar'   TheLabyrinth

The project cannot be built until build path errors are resolved    TheLabyrinth
```

So as you can see it doesn't seem to be working very good. But looking at the errors it seems to be something wrong with my pom.xml so here's a copy of that:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.awsp8.labyrinth</groupId>
  <artifactId>TheLabyrinth</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.0</version>
  <name>The Labyrinth</name>
  <description>You are stuck in a room,  no way out... Or so you think.</description>

  <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <natives.version>0.0.6</natives.version>
        <lwjgl.version>2.8.2</lwjgl.version>
        <slick.version>274</slick.version>
        <junit.version>4.10</junit.version>
    </properties>

  <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>mavenNatives</id>
            <name>Maven Natives Repository</name>
            <url>http://mavennatives.googlecode.com/svn/repo</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>

        <repository>
            <id>slick</id>
            <name>slick</name>
            <url>http://slick.cokeandcode.com/mavenrepo</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

<dependencies>  
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.lwjgl.lwjgl</groupId>
    <artifactId>lwjgl</artifactId>
    <version>2.8.4</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.lwjgl.lwjgl</groupId>
    <artifactId>lwjgl_util</artifactId>
    <version>2.8.4</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.lwjgl.lwjgl</groupId>
    <artifactId>lwjgl_util_applet</artifactId>
    <version>2.8.4</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
            <groupId>slick</groupId>
            <artifactId>slick</artifactId>
            <version>${slick.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>java3d</groupId>
            <artifactId>vecmath</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
</dependencies>

<plugin>
        <groupId>com.googlecode.mavennatives</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-nativedependencies-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.5</version>
        <executions>
                <execution>
                        <id>unpacknatives</id>
                        <phase>generate-resources</phase>
                        <goals>
                                <goal>copy</goal>
                        </goals>
                </execution>
        </executions>
</plugin>
</project>
```

Am I doing something wrong? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Many problems at once :)That pom.xml is incorrect? The plugins tag can't be on the "project" level? The slick.cokeandcode.com host is not resolvable. Is it "typesafe" slick you're looking for or is this some other library?

Comment: Oh, that's wierd, slick.cokeandcode.com doesn't exist. I took it off and now it works.